# Buttons not clickable + crashes app when clicked on

Tags: java, android

This is the crash error logcat, every single time I clock on my register btn the app crashes.

My emulator is at 2gb ram on an AndroidQ emulator device.

> 2019-09-22 16:36:39.307 6454-6454/com.connex.connexsocial E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>           Process: com.connex.connexsocial, PID: 6454
>           android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.connex.connexsocial/com.connex.connexsocial.LoginActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1933)
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1616)
>               at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4487)
>               at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:676)
>               at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4445)
>               at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:663)
>               at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4806)
>               at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4774)
>               at com.connex.connexsocial.MainActivity.openLoginActivity(MainActivity.java:50)
>               at com.connex.connexsocial.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:39)
>               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
>               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

This is my main_activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#7ed957"
    android:padding="20dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/logo1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo" />

        <!--Button: Register-->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/register_btn"
        android:text="@string/register"
        android:layout_above="@+id/login_btn"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <!--Button: Login-->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login_btn"
        android:text="@string/login"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Everytime I click on Login is does nothing, and everytime I click on Register it crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anytime your app crashes, the first debugging step should be to check your logcat, there are always clues in the logcat. If you checked the logs you posted, you'll see the line:

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.connex.connexsocial/com.connex.connexsocial.LoginActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Literally, this means that **you are getting this error because you have not declared the activity in your manifest**.

To fix this, simply paste this inside the application element of your manifest file:

```
<activity android:name="com.connex.connexsocial.LoginActivity"></activity>
```

This same debugging pattern works for almost every crash event. You'll always get a clue from your logcat.

Answer (score 2):

you need to declare LoginActivity in manifest file like
in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
android:name="com.connex.connexsocial.LoginActivity"
     />
```

Comment: Now app keeps crashing and doesn't open